# Transfer Magento API cart to Magento Store session

Tags: php, magento

first time with Magento, so sorry if it's a stupid question.

I have a website using the Magento API (get product list, information, and the cart) in python. I saw that the cart has is proper ID and session (it seems). Is there a way to transfer this cart / session in the Magento store ?

I started a new module/controller/action receiving a cart id from the API, but I can't figure it out on how to transfer the products from one to the other without calling the API again, from magneto.

Anyone has a clue ?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a way to do it properly. But used a workaround. I'm using the Magento API, inside a Magento controller/action to manually transfer the products. I don't like it, but it's the only way I found.